# Django serializer and display

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a one-to-many relationship model with payments and paymentlines. How can I group all the paymentlines with the same item and display in serializer. The key is the payments belong to the same order which order id is one the attributes in payments model.

views.py

```
class OrderItemViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Payment.objects.all()

def get_queryset(self):
    return self.queryset.filter(order_id=self.request.GET.get("order_id"))

serializer_class = PaymentSerializer
```

serializers.py:

```
class PaymentLineSerializer(ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model = PaymentLine
       fields = (
           "item_number",
           "currency",
           "available_quantity",
           "order_total_amount",
       )

class PaymentSerializer(ModelSerializer):

   payment_lines = PaymentLineSerializer(PaymentLine.objects.select_related("payment"), many=True)

   class Meta:
       model = Payment
       fields = ("order_id", "total_amount", "currency", "payment_lines")
```

To display this json:

```
[
    {
        "order_id": 4,
        "total_amount": "250.964024",     
        "currency": "USD",
        "payment_lines": [
            {
                "item_number": 1100,
                "currency": "USD",
                "available_quantity": 0,
                "order_total_amount": 0,
            },
            {
                "item_number": 1200,
                "currency": "USD",
                "available_quantity": 1,
                "order_total_amount": 224.982012,
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

instead of this:

```
[
    {
        "order_id": 4,
        "total_amount": "444.700000",
        "currency": "USD",
        "payment_lines": [
            {
                "item_number": 1100,
                "currency": "USD",
                "available_quantity": 1,
                "order_total_amount": 25.982012,

            },
            {
                "item_number": 1200,
                "currency": "USD",
                "available_quantity": 1,
                "order_total_amount": 224.982012,

            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "order_id": 4,
        "total_amount": "-25.982012",
        "external_reference_type": "MAG",
        "currency": "USD",
        "payment_lines": [
            {
                "item_number": 1100,
                "currency": "USD",
                "available_quantity": -1,
                "order_total_amount": -25.982012,

            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this. I assums that `paymentline_set` is your related name in models.py

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

class OrderItemViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
     def get_queryset(self):
         return Payment.objects.filter(
            order_id=self.request.GET.get("order_id")
         ).prefetch_related(
              Prefetch(
                  'paymentline_set',
                  queryset=PaymentLine.objects.all(),
                  to_attr='payment_lines'
              )
         )  

class PaymentSerializer(ModelSerializer):
     payment_lines = PaymentLineSerializer(many=True)
     class Meta:
         model = Payment
         fields = ("order_id", "total_amount", "currency", "payment_lines")
```

You can use without `Prefetch()`, but `.prefetch_related('paymentline_set')` then in `PaymentSerializer` change `payment_lines` to `paymentline_set`.